# Which spiral arm of the Milky Way is Kepler-62 in?

Tags: galaxy, exoplanet, milky-way, habitable-zone

I am trying to find out which spiral arm of the Milky Way the star Kepler-62 and its planetary system are in. All I can find by Google searching is that it is part of the Lyra constellation, but I don't know if that entire constellation is within 1 spiral arm or not, nor which arm it is in.

Is Kepler-62 in the Carina–Sagittarius Arm, or in the Orion Arm, or...?

The only map picture I can find that is somewhat related is this (I assume that the yellow light area is the area in which Kepler-62 was sighted by the Kepler spacecraft): http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/LombergA1024.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: Note that there are plenty of stars in between the spiral arms of the Milky Way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kepler space telescope had a field of view along the so called Orion arm, or spur, of the galaxy. The same structure which we ourselves are inside. It basically looks along a line where the star density is the greatest within the distance that it could detect transiting planets. Less than 3% of the galactic diameter, I think. Note that the illustration your question linked to seems to overestimate that distance. [One link](http://certificate.ulo.ucl.ac.uk/modules/year_one/NASA_Kepler/fov.html) and [another link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_(spacecraft)#Spacecraft_orbit_and_orientation). Kepler-62 and all another Kepler stars are certainly in that FOV. It would not be able to see transiting planets beyond the local arm. However, if the Kepler K2 mission gets going, it will use several different field of views.